# Unable to Sign In to Visual Studio 2013 and open Team Explorer after installing Update 5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Update 5 to my Visual Studio 2013, and now i can not sign in to my Microsoft Account or open Team Explorer view to work with Git.

When I click "Sign In" button in top right corner nothing happens (any bugs or warnings) - the login window does not appear. The same is with Team Explorer view - when I click View -> Team Explorer nothing happens. Befere I installed Update 5 I used it to work with GIT.

Maybe this will be helpful. First time I cancelled Update installation but the second time it was installed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of us had this problem at work and had to uninstall then reinstall Visual Studio, at which point it worked fine. I'm not entirely sure what the issue was or if there's a better way to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a better way to solve it. I do not have enough time to reinstall VS.